# Удаление данных из таблицы PostgreSQL. Как ведут себя данные при удалении?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Представим, что у меня есть таблица с 10 записями, и я удаляю первые 3 записи (строки) из таблицы. Затем сразу после этого вставляются новые 4 записи (строки) в таблицу. Мой вопрос заключается в том, смещаются ли оставшиеся 4-10 записи вверх, занимая место удаленных 1-3 записей, и новые 4 записи вставляются на места 8-11, или сначала 3 из 4 новых записей займут места 1-3, а 4 запись будет внесена в 11 строку?

Comment: При выполнении DELETE строки на самом деле остаются в таблице, лишь помечаясь как удалённые. Физически они будут удалены при выполнении операции VACUUM.

Comment: И вообще, расположение строк (кортежей) на странице зависит от наличия/отсутствия кластерного индекса, от сжатия, использования механизма TOAST, партицирования и других факторов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблица в БД это не таблица excel. В частности, записи не имеют порядка.

Представьте, что записи это файлы в каталоге. У них нет определенного порядка. Можно только при отображении списка (==выборки из таблицы) отсортировать их в желаемом порядке.

Т.е. если вам нужно чтоб записи имели порядок, нужно создать поле со значением (например числом), которое будет задавать порядок. При удалении и вставке, какие значения присвоите, такая логика порядка и будет.

Comment: Понял! Благодарю Вас за ответ!